# Remove overlay on press on BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDFZi.png)

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 10,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFBFBFB),
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.redeem,
                  style: Styles.grey13Medium,
                )
              ],
            ),
            activeIcon: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.redeem,
                  style: Styles.blue13Medium,
                )
              ],
            ),
            label: 'Redeem',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      )
```

we try to change in overlay but I didn't find overlay property in BottomNavigationBar and BottomNavigationBarItem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Make your code more readable**

> If you want to remove splash on bottom Nav bar, you can set it's color to transparent,

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: ChildWidget(),
);
```